# Group claims in roles ASP.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, claims

I'd like to make a system with granular permissions so
Is there a way to make groups of claims and assign them to a role so when a user gets a role it gets all the claims?
Is it possible to create groups of claims or am I misunderstanding something?

I'm failling to find the purpose of claims.
This could be done using groups with various roles and the roles are gonna be the permissions, right? This is the way I should do it? Since roles per se are claims.

Comment: If they are in a role then by association they have all permissions for that role. It's only a matter of looking them up at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following steps can solve your problem

1. Create granular level of roles...typically for each action
2. Group them up into GroupRoles...so that admin can easily manage it
3. Add individual level claims to user for specific permission

Some good examples of the same are below

- http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/granular-level-user-and-role-management-using-asp-net-identity
- http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/11/asp-net-identity-2-1-roles-based-authorization-authentication-asp-net-web-api/

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: The first link points to a Group based implementation (in CodeProject), which has a good idea, but a poor implementation in my opinion (it uses groups but internally, it adds the user to every role in the group and vice-versa). The second link is broken atm.